# i have a problem with my tic tac toe python game

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop, logic

the problem is after showing the winner it doesn't scape the loop. it ask the player to say where he wants to put X. I would really appreciate if you guys could help me with this.
I want it to start the game. be playable turn based and when someone wins shows the winner and ask if they wanna play again

```
import random

try:
    print("Welcome to Tic Tac Toe \n======================")
    Running = 1

    while Running == 1:
        possible_numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
        game_board = [["1","2","3"],["4","5","6"],["7","8","9"]]

        def print_game_board():
            print("+---+---+---+")
            print(f"| {game_board[0][0]} | {game_board[0][1]} | {game_board[0][2]} |")
            print("+---+---+---+")
            print(f"| {game_board[1][0]} | {game_board[1][1]} | {game_board[1][2]} |")
            print("+---+---+---+")
            print(f"| {game_board[2][0]} | {game_board[2][1]} | {game_board[2][2]} |")
            print("+---+---+---+")

        GG = False
        def check_for_winner():
            if game_board[0][0] == game_board[0][1] == game_board[0][2]:
                print(f"{game_board[0][0]} has won the game")
                GG = True
            elif game_board[1][0] == game_board[1][1] == game_board[1][2]:
                print(f"{game_board[1][0]} has won the game")
                GG = True
            elif game_board[2][0] == game_board[2][1] == game_board[2][2]:
                print(f"{game_board[2][0]} has won the game")
                GG = True
            elif game_board[0][0] == game_board[1][0] == game_board[2][0]:
                print(f"{game_board[0][0]} has won the game")
                GG = True
            elif game_board[0][1] == game_board[1][1] == game_board[2][1]:
                print(f"{game_board[0][1]} has won the game")
                GG = True
            elif game_board[0][2] == game_board[1][2] == game_board[2][2]:
                print(f"{game_board[0][2]} has won the game")
                GG = True
            elif game_board[0][0] == game_board[1][1] == game_board[2][2]:
                print(f"{game_board[0][0]} has won the game")
                GG = True
            elif game_board[0][2] == game_board[1][1] == game_board[2][0]:
                print(f"{game_board[0][2]} has won the game")
                GG = True
        print_game_board()
        print("You are going to play as X")
        turn = 0
    
        while G

G == False:
            if (turn % 2) == 0 :
                user_input = int(input("What number do you wanna put your X? 1-9 "))
                possible_numbers.remove(user_input)

                if user_input == 1:
                    game_board[0][0] = "X"
                elif user_input == 2:
                    game_board[0][1] = "X"
                elif user_input == 3:
                    game_board[0][2] = "X"
                elif user_input == 4:
                    game_board[1][0] = "X"
                elif user_input == 5:
                    game_board[1][1] = "X"
                elif user_input == 6:
                    game_board[1][2] = "X"
                elif user_input == 7:
                    game_board[2][0] = "X"
                elif user_input == 8:
                    game_board[2][1] = "X"
                elif user_input == 9:
                    game_board[2][2] = "X"

                turn += 1
                print_game_board()
                check_for_winner()
                
            
            if (turn % 2) == 1 :
                print("Now it's computer turn")
                comp_choice = random.choice(possible_numbers)
                possible_numbers.remove(comp_choice)

                if comp_choice == 1:
                    game_board[0][0] = "O"
                elif comp_choice == 2:
                    game_board[0][1] = "O"
                elif comp_choice == 3:
                    game_board[0][2] = "O"
                elif comp_choice == 4:
                    game_board[1][0] = "O"
                elif comp_choice == 5:
                    game_board[1][1] = "O"
                elif comp_choice == 6:
                    game_board[1][2] = "O"
                elif comp_choice == 7:
                    game_board[2][0] = "O"
                elif comp_choice == 8:
                    game_board[2][1] = "O"
                elif comp_choice == 9:
                    game_board[2][2] = "O"

                print("Computer has played its turn")
                print_game_board()
                check_for_winner()
                turn += 1
           
        wanna_play = input("do you wanna play another round? yes/no ").lower()
        if wanna_play == "yes":
            Running = 1
        else:
            print("Thanks for playing")
            quit()

except (ValueError, TypeError):
    quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of code here, but what you have is a scope problem. I'll make it much smaller so you can see the problem without the clutter. Consider this code:

```
def outer_function():
    GG = False

    def inner_function():
        GG = True

    print(GG)

outer_function() # prints `False`
```

It will print `False`, because `GG = True` isn't setting `GG` to `True` in the  outer function, it is shadowing it.

Instead, try `return`ing a value:

```
def outer_function():
    GG = False

    def inner_function():
        return True

    GG = inner_function()
    print(GG)

outer_function() # prints `True`
```

Thus, `check_for_winner` should return `True` if there is a winner, and `False` if there is not a winner. When you call this function, write:

```
GG = check_for_winner()
```

---

You can further simplify this. You have:

```
while GG == False:
    ...
```

but, if you make the above change, you can just write:

```
while not check_for_winner():
    ...
```

or, you can rename this function to `is_winner`

```
while not is_winner():
    ...
```